# grabbing upper 4 bytes of a 8 byte word

Tags: c++, c, long-long

I am multiplying `0x1d400 * 0xE070381D`.

When I do this on my calculator the result is `0x00019A4D26950400`

When I tried implementing this in cpp here's what i have.

```
long long d;

d = 3765450781 * 1d400;
```

The result this code gives is that `d = 0x26950400`. 
This is only the bottom 4 bytes, what happened to everything else?

I am trying to isolate the upper 4 bytes `0x00019A4D` and save them into another variable. How can this be done?

If I could get the multiplication to display all 8 bytes what I was thinking of doing to isolate the upper 4 bytes was:

```
d = d & 0xFF00; //0xFF00 == (binary) 1111111100000000

d = d>>8;
```

Will this work?

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: Do you want 16 bytes or 8 bytes? Your calculator result shows 16 hex digits, which is 8 bytes, not 16.

Comment: I think he wants 8 bytes, but counted 16 digits. I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 6):

Add `LL` after the numbers (e.g. `3765450781LL`) otherwise they are calculated as `int`s and the rest is chopped off before the assignment to `d`.

Comment: Depending on your compiler, 3765450781 (without `LL`) may be another type than `int`. Numbers above 32767 are not guaranteed to fit in an `int`. In particular, on many reasonable systems it will be an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `LL` after your constant for a `long long`, as indicated in another answer by MByD.

In addition, your data type should be `unsigned long long`.  Oherwise when you right shift, you may get the leftmost bit repeated due to sign-extend. (That is machine-dependent, but most machines sign extend negative numbers when right shifting.)

You do not need to mask off the upper 4 bytes before right shifting, because you are going to throw away the lower 4 bytes any way when you do the right shift.

Finally, note that the argument to `>>` is the number of **bits** to shift, not bytes. Therefore, you want

```
d = d >> 32;
```

Which can also be written as

```
d >>= 32;
```

Comment: He wants >>32, because he wants only the upper 4 bytes and not 8

Comment: @drhirsch Yes, I just realized that. Thanks.  Was just thinking in terms of number of bits to shift, and forgetting that there are only 64 bits in a long long.

Answer (score 1):

As the others pointed out, you must suffix your 64-bit numeric literals with `LL`.

To print your `long long` variable in hex, use the format specifier `"%016llX"`:

```
long long d;
d = 3765450781LL * 0x1d400LL;
printf("%016llX\n", d);
```

outputs `00019A4D26950400`.

To get the upper and lower 32 bits (4 bytes) of the variable `d`, you can do:

```
unsigned int upper;
unsigned int lower;

upper = d >> 32;
lower = d & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;

printf("upper: %08X lower: %08X\n", upper, lower);
```